# Array of different components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to make a post editor, which contains of certain fields like a title, publish date, etc.

The content however is in the form of 'blocks' which I made components for, an image block, a text block and a video block.

But I want to have an array of those blocks, of which I can iterate through using:

```
<component v-for="block in blocks" :is="block.type" :block="block"></component>
<span v-if="!blocks.length" class="text-muted">Empty! Click <strong>blocks</strong> to add a content block</span>
```

The array is comprised of objects with a type attribute set to either `image-block`, `text-block` or `video-block`..

This sort of works, but when I submit the form I want to go through the blocks and get the data inside it, but I can't.. Not can I remove the block with an X inside the template because I can't remove the object in the array of the parent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post a fiddle